# Unable to create Service in Azure Service Fabric Cluster [.NET 6 and ASP.NET Core 6.0] through Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

We have couple of stateless services deployed into Azure Service Fabric cluster (developed in ASP.NET Core 2.1), all are up and running, I started to upgrade one of the services to .NET 6 (ASP.NET Core 6), newly created service tested locally and deploying into Azure Service Fabric cluster through Azure DevOps pipeline (CI/CD). Post successful deployment, service is not available in SF Cluster whereas I can see the application, even I **did not see error during deployment (CD) for the Deploy Service Fabric deployment task**.

[image]

However, I can **publish the application through Visual Studio 2022** and service is running into Azure Service Fabric cluster. But unable to deploy API through Azure DevOps Release Pipeline with 'Deploy Service Fabric Application Deployment' task, although old ASP.NET Core 2.1 application deploying successfully with same task.

[image]

systems

- Windows 10 Enterprise
- .NET 6
- ASP.NET Core 6.0
- Visual Studio 2022 Professional (Version 17.2.5)

Azure DevOps Pipeline

CI for Service Fabric application

[image]

Update service manifest task
[image]

CD

[image]

Deploy Service Fabric task log showing Removing application from image store, even I can't see the DNS name during deployment which I mention in StartupServices.xml

[image]

Settings in CD for Deploy Service Fabric task

[image]

Comment: Do you get an error on the deploy service fabric application task? Is the deployment completed?

Comment: Nope, did not get any error during deployment. CD succeeded.

Comment: If the deployment succeeds and the service fabric task starts upgrading the cluster nodes, then there should be an error from your application. What is the behavior that you notice? Maybe you have selected skip upgrade for same type and version and the application is not upgrading

Comment: After deployment did not see error during upgradation of the cluster nodes. post successful release heath state is "OK". I have selected "Overwrite Behaviour"  - " Always" and Checked "Override All Publish Profile Upgrade Setting", "Upgrade The application", Checked "Unregistered Unused Version". I'm unable to triage the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deployed the service in the existing cluster [earlier version was ASP.NET Core 2.1] with existing CI/CD and it works.
But still I don't know why I'm unable to deploy new service in the cluster which developed on top of .NET 6.0 version.